# LAIR ResourceAPIs Wordnet in C#

Tags: c#, wordnet

I have a C# Project that uses WordNet 3.0 techniques,

one of the C# codes uses the 'LAIR' Library that related to WordNet,

```
using LAIR.ResourceAPIs.WordNet;
using LAIR.Collections.Generic;
```

when I try to build the project it says that LAIR could not be found and I think the assembly reference to it is missing.

what are the library or dll files that I should add them to my project to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try going here:
https://code.google.com/p/opensim4opencog/source/browse/trunk/lib/NLPLibs.net/LAIR.ResourceAPIs.WordNet.dll?r=1327

find "View Raw File" and RIGHT click it, and download it.

then try this one

https://code.google.com/p/opensim4opencog/source/browse/trunk/lib/NLPLibs.net/LAIR.Collections.dll?r=1327&spec=svn1327

for the collections.

However, I think you must have missed some kind of installation step.  The actual .dll's should be here though. (look through the dropdown).

Comment: I've found those, I think I should have the whole 3rd party library (if there's any) because it loads dictionary wordnet files,
I think having the 2 dlls only won't be enough, I'd give it a shot though.